# Jasmine test with Require/Backbone project

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, tdd, requirejs, jasmine

My objective is to test the TDD (Test driven development). But after one weekend on it , I really need your help :)

> First Question : "What is the best way to TDD between Browser runner
>   or headless runner" ?

Second : I really want test my project without browser before put it in Production mode. For while I didn't succeed :(

For example if I want test my Projects model who look like :

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var projectsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      score: 10
    },
    initialize: function(){
    }

  });
  return projectsModel;
});
```

How can I do ? 
I have already check jasmine-node / Js test driver / ... but without success :/
Jasmine-node look great but... I need some help because every tuto I found on web only work for simple model without Require dependence...

Thank you :)

PS : I also check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929435/require-js-and-js-test-driver-unexpected-token) but with the same error :/

Answer (score 1):

Node has issues emulating a real browser, with all it's quirks, ajax, etc.  Something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) works damn well though.  You use a script to open your test running page and let it run in PhantomJS, and have some other code to pull out the results.

Comment: I have read that PhantomJs (like selenium) is more for "behavior" test than real Javascript unit test.Is it true ? Because in reality, I didn't really need a browser... I just want my unit test :)

Comment: PhantomJS is a browser, just with no visible renderer.  If you don't need a browser at all, then I totally don't understand your question.

Comment: @AlexWayne - He wants to test the _logic_ of his javascript without actually running it in a browser.